# Unable to bind list variable from thymleaf view in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am binding a list to field from thymleaf view, but getting null in the controller. Consider it is not `null` in view.

```
<form th:object="${obj}"
  <input type="hidden" th:field="*{someList}" th:value="${obj.getSomeList()}">
```

POJO is like this:

```java
public class Foo {
  private int id;
  private List<Some> someList;

  //setter getter

}
```

If I bind the `id` in same way I am getting it in controller, pls help If I have take special care for `List`.

My controller:

```
@RequestMapping
public String bar(@ModelAttribute("obj") Foo foo)
```

Comment: Hi Anil where are looping here ?You need to have a each loop tag to get the list item <th:block th:each="${obj}">

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36500731/how-to-bind-an-object-list-with-thymeleaf

Comment: @Pradeep ${obj} is not the list, it's variable is a list. I am wondering if I can get the whole value it, when it is already set/available.

Comment: plus 1 Thanks, its weird but gotta do it this way.

Comment: so you were able to get the things done by creating a foreach loop.Shall I goahead and create an answer so that you will accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Anil after setting the values to a variable you need to iterate through the list using the each tag
Pls find the syntax

```html
<form th:object="${obj}" th:action="@{/list}" action="void(0)" method="post">
    <tr>    
        <td th:field="*{id}" th:text="${obj.id}" /> 
    </tr>
    <tr th:each="l , i : ${obj.someList}">
        <input type="hidden" th:field="*{someList[__${i.index}__].something}" />
    </tr>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" />
</form>
```