# cannot bind a list of object using thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring, thymeleaf

*Even if it's not related to the question, you can tell me if there's anything wrong with the code.*

First, i applied the approach of adding table rows and adding input tags by modal. It was implemented by referring to [How to bind an object list with thymeleaf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36500731/how-to-bind-an-object-list-with-thymeleaf).
But it fails to bind and `optionRequests` becomes null.

What did I miss? I don't know what the problem is.

#### html & javascript

```html
<form id="example-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title" required>
  <input type="file" accept="image/*" class="form-control" id="imgFile" name="imgFile">
    
  <input type="button" value="Add Option" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#optionModal">
  </div>
  <div class="modal fade" id="optionModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="optionModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="optionModalLabel">option</h1>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="optionName">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="addValue">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="method">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="material">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addOptionRow()">Add</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <table class="table table-bordered" id="optionTable">
     <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>AddValue</th>
        <th>Method</th>
        <th>Material</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

      </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

```js
<script>
  function addOptionRow() {
      const table = document.getElementById('optionTable');
      const newRow = table.insertRow();
      const optionName = newRow.insertCell(0);
      const addValue = newRow.insertCell(1);
      const method = newRow.insertCell(2);
      const material = newRow.insertCell(3);
      const removeButton = newRow.insertCell(4);
      var idx = $('#optionTable tr').length - 2;

      optionNameText = $('#optionName').val();
      addValueText = $('#addValue').val();
      methodText = $('#method').val();
      materialText = $('#material').val();

      optionName.innerText = optionNameText;
      addValue.innerText = addValueText;
      method.innerText = methodText;
      material.innerText = materialText;
      removeButton.innerHTML = "<button class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' onclick='removeRow(this)'>X</button>"

      $("#example-form").append($("<input type='hidden' th:field='${example.optionRequests[" + idx + "].optionName}' th:name='${example.optionRequests[" + idx + "]}' th:value='" + optionNameText + "'>"));
      $("#example-form").append($("<input type='hidden' th:field='${example.optionRequests[" + idx + "].addValue}' th:name='${example.optionRequests[" + idx + "]}' th:value='" + addValueText + "'>"));
      $("#example-form").append($("<input type='hidden' th:field='${example.optionRequests[" + idx + "].method}' th:name='${example.optionRequests[" + idx + "]}' th:value='" + methodText + "'>"));
      $("#example-form").append($("<input type='hidden' th:field='${example.optionRequests[" + idx + "].material}' th:name='${example.optionRequests[" + idx + "]}' th:value='" + materialText + "'>"));

      $('#optionName').val("");
      $('#addValue').val("");
      $('#method').val("");
      $('#material').val("");
      $('#optionModal').modal('hide');
    }
</script>
```

---

The DTO is defined as follows.

#### FormRequest

```java
public record FormRequest(
        String title,
        List<OptionRequest> optionRequests,
        MultipartFile imgFile
) {}
```

#### OptionRequest

```java
public record OptionRequest(
        String optionName,
        Integer addValue,
        String method,
        String material
) {
}
```

---

The controller is implemented as follows.

#### Controller

```java
    @GetMapping("/example")
    public String exampleGet(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("example", new FormResponse(null, List.of(), null)); //Same field as in FormRequest
       
        return "form";
    }
    @PostMapping("/example")
    public String examplePost(
            @ModelAttribute("example") FormRequest formRequest,
            Model model
    ) {}
```

---

Thymeleaf is implemented as follows by applying the decoupled logic.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<thlogic>
    ...
    <attr sel="#example-form" th:object="${example}" th:action="/example" th:method="post">
        <attr sel="#title" th:value="*{title} ?: _"/>
    ...
</thlogic>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was resolved by modifying it as follows.

1. Change record dto to class dto and add getter, setter
2. Modified th:field, th:name, th:value to name, value